# CVS status - show remotely added (new, never checked out) files?

Tags: cvs

Executing `cvs status` lists the status of all **local** (already checked out or added) files.

Does anybody know an option (or any other way) to list files, which are remotely added and have never been checked out in the local folders (`cvs update` "downloads" them, but can I list them in some way)?

---

There should be a way, because eclipse's "Synchronize with repository" can list them, before checking them out. But I can't figure out how does Eclipse deal with this.

---

Something not-so-relevant - this is how I check status:

```
alias cvsstatus_command='cvs -q status 2>&1 | grep -E "^[?F]|cvs status:" | grep -v "Up-to-date"'
alias cvsstatus_color='nawk -W interactive '"'"'BEGIN { arr["\\? "] = "0;32"; arr["Needs Merge"] = "0;31"; arr["Needs Patch"] = "1;31"; arr["[cC]onflict"] = "1;33"; arr["[Rr]emoved"] = "1;33"; arr["Locally Modified"] = "0;33"; arr["Locally Added"] = "0;32" } { l = $0; for (pattern in arr) { gsub(".*" pattern ".*", "\033[" arr[pattern] "m&\033[0m", l); } print l; }'"'"
alias cvsstatus='cvsstatus_command | cvsstatus_color'
```

This ignores all files, which are up-to-date, outputs status for the other files in one line per file and colorizes the different types of changes. Could be useful for somebody. It can also be easily extended.